# UISearchController issues with iPhone X when status bar is hidden

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I modified Apples example UISearchController project to allow it to work with iPhone X by embedding the UISearchController into the UINavigationController as apple suggests like:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
} else {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

Everything works as expected, however when I remove the status bar of the project things seem to break. When you tap the search area the NavigationBar disappears and you can even slide the search result table up behind things like the image shows. Having the status bar in the app fixes things.

Modified project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fdtwm361cy8e98/TableSearchwithUISearchController.zip?dl=0

[image]

Even on other phones hiding status bar the search field is too close to the top now:

[image]

I want the same behavior and spacing with the status bar hidden as with it showing, anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Same problem here, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, setting the `UISearchController` property `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to `false` helps in providing a non-broken user experience. Found the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320791/uisearchcontroller-hiding-status-bar-on-ios-11-swift-4).