# UISearchController hiding status bar on iOS 11 Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I have one `searchViewController` which have `navigationBar` color as DarkBlue and when i search and get result on click of that i have viewController with navigationBar color as white... 
So when i came back to `searchViewController` my `statusBar` will get hide with white color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: where you set the status bar color

Comment: Not setting status bar color anywhere... i am just setting the navigationBar color according to my controller for searchViewController my navigation color is DarkBlue and for other viewController navigation C=color is white

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: Its look like your status bar color set to its default state....after getting back to the previous VC ... do set your status bar code in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: The animation which pop ups the searchcontroller is weird first it is white then changes to DarkBlue

Comment: for quick solution do animated false

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will solve your problem.

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```